# How to create and return PNG with fpWeb?

Tags: http, web, png, pascal, lazarus

I want to create PNG image on the fly and return it using HTTP-server from fpWeb package.

```pascal
procedure TFPWebModule1.DataModuleRequest(Sender: TObject; ARequest: TRequest;
  AResponse: TResponse; var Handled: Boolean);
var
  png: Graphics.TPortableNetworkGraphic;
begin
  png := Graphics.TPortableNetworkGraphic.Create;
  try
    png.SetSize(100, 100);
    png.Canvas.TextOut(10, 10, 'Hello world!');

    AResponse.ContentType:='image/png';
    AResponse.ContentStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
    png.SaveToStream(AResponse.ContentStream);
    AResponse.ContentLength := AResponse.ContentStream.Size;
    AResponse.SendContent;
    AResponse.ContentStream := nil;
  finally
    png.Free;
  end;

  Handled:=true;
end;
```

But application crashes on the line `png.SetSize` with error `External: SIGSEGV`. How can I fix this?

I use latest Lazarus 2.0.12 (32bit) on Windows 7 (64bit).

Comment: I never use the graphic (whcih is more for form display), I usually use tlazintfimage or fpimage image types for this, and it is possible that the graphic is only a shell around those  Give it a try to use them directly.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this code Which i modified from yours.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  png: Graphics.TPortableNetworkGraphic;
begin
  png := Graphics.TPortableNetworkGraphic.Create;

    png.SetSize(100, 100);
    png.Canvas.TextOut(10, 10, 'Hi artem!');
    png.SaveToFile('tst.png');
end;
```

And I got this image saved.

[image]

I think nothing wrong with your code in regards to PNG image.
I think it may be cause by other thing. Maybe DataModuleRequest not allow to have any graphics or UI-load processing or something. Not sure.